# Выборка полей по типу в объекте

Tags: javascript

Необходимо для каждого объекта в массиве проверить все свойства и вернуть новый массив объектов с примитивными типами. Т.е. из массива

```
[
        {
            name: 'Ivan',
            definition: {
                head: true
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'Fedor',
            definition: {
                head: false
            }
        }
    ]
```

Получаем массив объектов, не имеющих свойств с типом object

```
    [
        { name: 'Ivan'},
        { name: 'Fedor'}
    ]
```

Как можно организовать такой парсинг?

Comment: является ли функция примитивным типом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вопросе можно выделить три задачи:

1. Проверить значение на примитивность
2. Создать новый объект на основе старого, без некоторых ключей.
3. Построить новый массив на основе старого.

Для решения первой, нужно определиться что именно считать примитивными типами: если только строки и числа - это одно условие, если дополнительно к ним еще и `null`,`undefined`,`function` - уже другое.

Для примера возьмем только строки и числа, тогда проверку можно вынести в такую функцию isPrimitive

```
function isPrimitive(o){
    return typeof o == 'string' || typeof o == 'number';
}
```

Для решения второй, можно воспользоваться функцией [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce): применив ее к массиву ключей, можно свернуть его в объект без ненужных свойств, например тка:

```
Object.keys(o).reduce((acc,key)=>{
    if(isPrimitive(o[key]))
        acc[key] = o[key];

    return acc;
},{});
```

Для решения третьей - воспользоваться функцией [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

В сборе все может выглядеть так:

```js
var array = [{
  name: 'Ivan',
  definition: {
    head: true
  }
}, {
  name: 'Fedor',
  definition: {
    head: false
  }
}];

function isPrimitive(o) {
  return typeof o == 'string' || typeof o == 'number';
}
var newArray = array.map(o =>
  Object.keys(o).reduce((acc, key) => {
    if (isPrimitive(o[key]))
      acc[key] = o[key];
    return acc;
  }, {}));

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Циклы, так или иначе:

```js
var test = [{
  name: 'Ivan',
  definition: {
    head: true
  }
}, {
  name: 'Fedor',
  definition: {
    head: false
  }
}];
var newArray = [];

for (var i in test) {
  var obj = {};
  for (var j in test[i]) {
    if (typeof test[i][j] != 'object') {
      obj[j] = test[i][j];
    }
  }
  newArray.push(obj);
}

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: первый цикл лучше сделать обычным `for`, или `for..of`, а не `for..in`

Answer (score 1):

Либо с использованием ES6:

```js
let array = [{
  name: 'Ivan',
  definition: {
    head: true
  }
}, {
  name: 'Fedor',
  definition: {
    head: false
  }
}];


let newArray = array.map(entry => {
  let newEntry = {};
  Object.keys(entry).forEach(key => {
    let value = entry[key];
    if (typeof(value) != 'object') {
      newEntry[key] = value;
    }
  });
  return newEntry;
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: "циклы, так или иначе" :)

Comment: @Bookin, вы правы :)
Просто, лично для меня, запись в ES6 выглядит немного читабельней, хоть это и не было предметом вопроса.

Comment: для меня наоборот, я хоть и понимаю что происходит, но со всеми этими стрелками, мозг не хочет воспринимать картину. Ну а так, да, ES6 в массы, то пока мало где он встречается в примерах.